# Transformations relating 3F2 at z with 3F2's at 1/z

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-function

I am searching for some transformations for a 3F2 hypergeometric function which send the argument z to 1/z. I am aware of the one given in NIST book (p. 410, Formula 16.8.8) in the special case q=2 (with the notations given in there). However, that requires the differences between the top parameters a1, a2, and a3 (taken two at a time) to not be integers. I was wondering if there are transformations in which this condition could be relaxed. I see most of the results involve unit argument which is not what I am seeking. Any reference in this regard will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: If $a_i-a_j\in\mathbb Z$, then $_3F_2(\ldots,1/z)$ are not defined and the basis of solutions at $z=\infty$ has a more involved form (local expansions of solutions also involve logarithmic terms, see for example 15.3.14 in Abramowitz-Stegun in the case of $_2F_1$). I cannot provide a reference for analogous result for $_3F_2$, meanwhile it should be known since the connection formulas between the two bases of solutions can be obtained from the Mellin-Barnes integrals, see e.g. Section 4.2 of https://pages.uoregon.edu/njp/beukers.pdf for the non-resonant case.

Comment: Thanks very much for the information!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the answer is no. In the case of connection formulas that bring you to $z\rightarrow\frac{1}{z}$ the coefficients $(a_1-a_2),(a_1-a_3),(a_2-a_3)\not\in\mathbb{Z}$ because the $\Gamma$ Euler function is not defined in $\mathbb{Z}^-$. To convince yourself you can see that also for the Gaussian hypergemetric function $_2F_1$ there is a similar limitation[image]

Alternatively you can look ([here](http://apps.nrbook.com/bateman/Vol1.pdf) at pag.190) the transformation formula proposed by Whipple (1927) for $z\rightarrow\frac{-4z}{(1-z)^2}$ and by Bailey (1929)for $z\rightarrow\frac{-27z}{4*(1-z)^3}$, but both only for particular combinations of the Pochhammer coefficients.