# Transformations relating ${}_3F_2$ at z with ${}_3F_2$ at $\frac{1}{1-z}$

Tags: transformation, hypergeometric-function

I am searching for some transformations for a ${}_{3}F_2$ hypergeometric function which send the argument $z$ to $\frac{1}{1-z}$, or any other forms where I can interpret ${}_3F_2$ as a Laplace transform. I am aware of the transformation sending $z$ to $\frac{1}{z}$:

[Transformations relating 3F2 at z with 3F2's at 1/z](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3222972/transformations-relating-3f2-at-z-with-3f2s-at-1-z)

Of course, if there is a general formula for ${}_{p+1}F_p$, that would be much appreciated.

I understand how to do this for ${}_2F_1$, but there are two steps in the proof (Lebedev's book), and it seems we do not have that for ${}_3F_2$.

Comment: Try to not use the same exact title as the linked question

Comment: you may have luck with the integral representation $$_3F_2\left(\small{{a_1, a_2,a_3}\atop{b_1,b_2}}; z\right)=\frac{\Gamma(b_2)}{\Gamma(a_3)\Gamma(b_2-a_3)}\int_0^1 t^{a_3-1}(1-t)^{b_2-a_3-1}\,_2F_1\left(\small{{a_1,a_2}\atop{b_1}};zt\right)dt$$ for $\Re(b_2)>\Re(a_3)>0$. Or any contor integral you find [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric3F2/07/).

Comment: Thanks for that. This was my first attempt. However, I ended with a double summation which I do not know how to further simplified.

Comment: could you include your efforts in your question? you would certainly earn an upvote from me.

Comment: There is no such formula for $_3F_2$.  You may have a look to http://fe.math.kobe-u.ac.jp/FE/FullPapers/51-1/51_107.pdf for a useful discussion.

Comment: Thanks for this interesting paper. After I have read through the proof for this transformation under ${}_2F_1$ in the Lebedev's book, my feeling is that: first, we cannot solve this through the differential equation, although it works under ${}_2F_1$; second, even we are able to solve the differential equation, we cannot figure out the coefficients of solutions, due to lack of a general formula of ${_3F_2(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3;\beta_1,\beta_2;1)}$. I am still working on this.